# FTP not working in apache camel

Tags: ftp, apache-camel

I was trying apache camel built in examples for ftp and incorporate with `springboot`. When executing neither I am getting an error message not file download. Below is the code snippet and logs. From the logs I could see server is connected succesfully, but I am not able to see the file in `/tmp/` folder.

```
2016-03-18 15:21:02.744  INFO 2103 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 2.16.2 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
2016-03-18 15:21:02.744  INFO 2103 --- [           main] o.a.c.m.ManagedManagementStrategy        : JMX is enabled
2016-03-18 15:21:02.805  INFO 2103 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.DefaultRuntimeEndpointRegistry   : Runtime endpoint registry is in extended mode gathering usage statistics of all incoming and outgoing endpoints (cache limit: 1000)
2016-03-18 15:21:02.883  INFO 2103 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : AllowUseOriginalMessage is enabled. If access to the original message is not needed, then its recommended to turn this option off as it may improve performance.
2016-03-18 15:21:02.883  INFO 2103 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
2016-03-18 15:21:03.711  WARN 2103 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.file.remote.SftpOperations       : JSCH -> Permanently added '**<XXXXXX>**' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
2016-03-18 15:21:09.025  INFO 2103 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.file.remote.SftpOperations       : Connected to sftp://*****@*****:22
2016-03-18 15:21:09.058  INFO 2103 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Route: route1 started and consuming from: Endpoint[sftp://******:22/tmp/sample.txt?password=xxxxxx&username=*****]
2016-03-18 15:21:09.059  INFO 2103 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Total 1 routes, of which 1 is started.
2016-03-18 15:21:09.059  INFO 2103 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 2.16.2 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 6.316 seconds
2016-03-18 15:21:09.105  INFO 2103 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-03-18 15:21:09.106  INFO 2103 --- [           main] o.apache.camel.spring.boot.FatJarRouter  : Started FatJarRouter in 10.232 seconds (JVM running for 10.651)
```

And the code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringBootRouter extends FatJarRouter {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception{

       // configure properties component
       PropertiesComponent pc = getContext().getComponent("properties", PropertiesComponent.class);
       pc.setLocation("classpath:ftp.properties");

       // lets shutdown faster in case of in-flight messages stack up
       getContext().getShutdownStrategy().setTimeout(10);

       from("sftp://<mylinuxserver>:22/tmp/sample.txt?username=abc&password=123")
            .to("file:/tmp/sample.txt")
            .log("Downloaded file ${file:name} complete.");

       System.out.println("*********************************************************************************");
       // System.out.println("Camel will route files from the FTP server: "
       //        + getContext().resolvePropertyPlaceholders("{{ftp.server}}") + " to the target/download directory.");
       System.out.println("You can configure the location of the ftp server in the src/main/resources/ftp.properties file.");
       System.out.println("Use ctrl + c to stop this application.");
       System.out.println("*********************************************************************************");
    }
}
```

Comment: That *sftp* you're using, best swap that `ftp` tag for `ssh`. The log file would benefit from formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using
`Stepwise` option
and/or
`jschLoggingLevel` to `TRACE`

Also using Filezilla for verification using an app.